# Which codec will be used after sdp exchange in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, rtp, sdp

In a WebRTC video call

A->B a SDP offer, it means that A supports VP8, VP9 and H264

```
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 124 125
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
...
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
...
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
```

while B->A answered a SDP answer, it also means that B supports VP8, VP9 and H264

```
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 124 125
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
...
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
...
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
...
```

My question is in this case, which codec will be used? How A or B knows another choice?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be found in RFC3264.

[Section 5.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3264#section-5.1):

> If multiple formats are listed, it
> means that the offerer is capable of making use of any of those
> formats during the session.  In other words, the answerer MAY change
> formats in the middle of the session, making use of any of the
> formats listed, without sending a new offer.

The offerer will list the supported codecs in order of preference in the m-line. The answerer will most likely honor that preference, but is not obliged to do so. See [Section 6.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3264#section-6.1):

> Although the answerer MAY list the formats in their desired order of
> preference, it is RECOMMENDED that unless there is a specific reason,
> the answerer list formats in the same relative order they were
> present in the offer.

[Section 7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3264#section-7):

> When the offerer receives the answer, it MAY send media on the
> accepted stream(s) (assuming it is listed as sendrecv or recvonly in
> the answer).  It MUST send using a media format listed in the answer,
> and it SHOULD use the first media format listed in the answer when it
> does send.

So in short: the offerer and answerer will most likely use the first codec in the answerer's m-line and this may change during the media session.

Answer (score 0):

B signals that it would prefer 96, i.e. VP8 since that is listed first in the m= line formats.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/change-codecs/ has a sample allows you to change the order of codecs and inspect the results.